# Creating and calling custom controller actions in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In asp.net mvc 2 web application I've created a controller and default actions work just fine(Index, Display, Create). Now I want to create a custom controller action which takes an object id and named, say, Rotate, I've created a public method which does some logic and redirects to the index page again.

The problem is that when I'm trying to call

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Click on me", "Rotate", new { id = item.Id })%>
```

there's 404 error.
What's the problem? Should I register that created controller action somewhere in order to use it?

EDIT:

```
public ActionResult Rotate(int id)
            {
                /* does some stuff to the object */
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

URL is like this: http://localhost/Home/Rotate/1

Comment: Post source code for your action.

Comment: Please show us your controller and the generated URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller and action match your default route (controller / action / id) than you don't need to do anything else to 'register' your action.

*And you need to compile the project ;-)*

Comment: Index action shows the list of the objects, it works fine. The problem is with the Rotate action.

Comment: yes, localhost/Home works fine, it displays the list of the objects

Comment: Is `Rotate` action part of `HomeController` or some other controller?

Comment: Of course it's part of the HomeController. I've just added my own method to the controller.

Comment: Sorry to ask, just trying to rule out the obvious - have you compiled the project?

Comment: Jakub, OMG, I didn't compile it, just refreshed the browser. This is really funny. Thanks a lot.